# AWS SNS - how to customize the s3 event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I created s3 bucket with event enabled for the bucket. When the new object is uploaded to the bucket sns will trigger an event to lambda to extract content from the file.

Is there any way to customize the sns event in generic format.

Comment: I think this will help you https://mattgadient.com/2016/06/14/creating-custom-notification-text-with-amazon-s3-and-sns-via-lambda/

Comment: Why don't you just trigger Lambda directly from S3 event, instead of going through SNS?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-box way to customize the notification format (without involving a middleman like Lambda). I would suggest using AWS Lambda as the direct message destination instead of letting the S3 notification flows through SNS. This AWS documentation will be useful for you (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-walkthrough-2.html).